Am I eligible for a work visa for Hong Kong after overstaying in China?
I am a Filipino citizen and want to work in Hong Kong, but I overstayed in China more than 3 years. I reported to the authorities and I got an exit permit last March 2019. I am back in the Philippines.
Can I work in Hong Kong? And can I get a work visa?

How long was your overstay in China? Did you report your overstay to the authorities and did you get an exit permit when you left?

I overstayed more than 3years. Yes I report to authorities and I get exit permit last march 2019 I come back here at the philippines

It may depend on the type of work and the visa class you want to apply for. However typically past immigration law breaches tend at best to count against you and at worst can make you ineligible to apply.
For example, the Eligibility criteria for a New Foreign Domestic Helper visa states that offences under Immigration laws will be taken into account.
To find out for sure if you can get a work visa for Hong Kong, you could consult an Immigration adviser and/or you can apply and see what happens.
